# meaning of 'before'

Tags: meaning

Quote from Quora website.

> A BSc in a relevant field is sufficient. If your field was physics or
>   electrical engineering, then your degree would qualify. If your field
>   was psychology, then you would not be qualified.
>
> But let’s be clear about exactly what a patent attorney is. A patent
>   attorney is a lawyer who is qualified to practice **before** the patent
>   office. The patent office is where patent applications are examined
>   and patents are issued. Patent agents are non lawyers who practice
>   before the patent office.

I do not know the exact meaning of before in this paragraphs. I found the meaning on Google Dictionary, but was not able to find suitable meaning.

Comment: srry, spelling error. it is dic, not doc. The meanings I found are 

1. during the period of time preceding (a particular event, date, or time).
2. in front of

Comment: 3. in preference to; with a higher priority than.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the information you’re putting in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary [lists](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/before_1) several uses of **Before**, and the relevant one here is

> EXAMINATION
>
> being formally examined or considered by a group:
>
> the proposal before the committee
>
> He appeared before the court dressed in jeans.

Answer (score 0):

A Patent Attorney is a lawyer with advanced knowledge in Intellectual Property Law, and usually additional qualifications in Science, Engineering or Information Technology, who has been approved (or certified) by a particular patent authority as being entitled to prepare, amend and file patent applications on behalf of others with that patent office.

In 'qualified to practice before', 'before' means 'in front of'. It is a common legal phrase indicating that a lawyer is qualified (usually requiring a licensing or registration process) to represent a client in the clients dealings with a particular legal, or quasi-legal, court or authority.